# Turning If / Else conditions into for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, onclick

New developer currently taking courses, working on a trivia game project with Javascript & Jquery. I have a long if else condition, looking to see if I can put in a for loop to condense the code. or if there is any other method to shorten it? I have 8 total questions for the game.

```
if (question1 == "Red Hot Chili Peppers") {
        userCorrect ++;

    }else {
        userIncorrect ++;

    }

    if (question2 == "Rage Against The Machine") {
        userCorrect ++;

    }else {
        userIncorrect ++;

    }

    if (question3 == "Nirvana") {
        userCorrect ++;

    }else {
        userIncorrect ++;

    }

    if (question4 == "Sublime") {
        userCorrect ++;

    }else {
        userIncorrect ++;

    }

    if (question5 == "The Black Keys") {
        userCorrect ++;

    }else {
        userIncorrect ++;

    }

    if (question6 == "Dave Grohl") {
        userCorrect ++;

    }else {
        userIncorrect ++;

    }

    if (question7 == "Pearl Jam") {
        userCorrect ++;

    }else {
        userIncorrect ++;

    }

    if (question8 == "Big Gigantic") {
        userCorrect ++;

    }else {
        userIncorrect ++;

    }

}
```

The game works; however, looking to condense this down if possible.

Comment: Put your questions in an array or other collection, and use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of correct answers (and an array of questions) instead:

```
const correctAnswers = [
  "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
  "Rage Against The Machine",
  "Nirvana"
  // ...
];

// ...
// have userAnswers be an array of answers

const userCorrect = correctAnswers
  .filter((correctAnswer, i) => userAnswers[i] === correctAnswer)
  .length;
const userIncorrect = correctAnswers.length - userCorrect;
```

If you're familiar with `reduce`, you can remove the need for a `.length` check at the end, `reduce` is a bit more appropriate for transforming an array into a single expression:

```
const userCorrect = correctAnswers
  .reduce((a, correctAnswer, i) => a + userAnswers[i] === correctAnswer, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the correct answers in one array and the user's guesses in another. Then, loop over the correct answers and check it against the corresponding answer from the user's guesses array.

This can be implemented in a few different ways, but since you are just learning, I'm keeping it pretty simple. It relies on the first array being looped over with [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and then uses a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to decide if the score should be increased.

```js
const correctAnswers = [
  "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
  "Rage Against The Machine",
  "Nirvana"
];

let userAnswers = [
  "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
  "Green Day",
  "Nirvana"
];

let numberCorrect = 0;

// Loop over the right answers
correctAnswers.forEach(function(answer, index){
  // Increment the score if the user's answer matches the correct answer.
  numberCorrect = userAnswers[index] === answer ? numberCorrect + 1 : numberCorrect;
});

console.log("You got " + numberCorrect + " out of " + correctAnswers.length + " correct.");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you save que correct `answers` on an array and the user `responses` on another where the array indexes matchs answers with responses, you can use a loop to compare they and count the correct ones.

```js
const answers = [
    "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
    "Rage Against The Machine",
    "Nirvana",
    "Sublime",
    "The Black Keys",
    "Dave Grohl",
    "Pearl Jam",
    "Big Gigantic"
];

let userResponses = [
    "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
    "Pink Floyd",
    "Nirvana",
    "Sublime",
    "The Black Keys",
    "Bob Marley",
    "Pearl Jam",
    "Artic Monkeys"
];

let goods = 0;

userResponses.forEach((x, idx) =>
{
    goods += (x === answers[idx]);
});

console.log("Corrects: " + goods);
console.log("Incorrects: " + (answers.length - goods));
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: It is not, is similar, however I did not see your answer because I was making mine. There was only one answer when I started mine. If this is a problem for you, I can delete this one. I should train my fingers to type more faster...

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating an array of correct answers. Then, store all of the user's answers in a different array. Initialize the `correctCount` counter to 0 and use a simple `for loop` to loop through the list, comparing each value to the other. Also, since the `incorectCount` can be easily calculated, you don't have to count it separately.

```
const correctAnswers = [
  "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
  "Rage Against The Machine",
  "Nirvana",
  "Sublime"
];

const userAnswers = [
  "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
  "Rage Against The Machine",
  "Nirvana",
  "Metallica"
];

let correctCount = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++) {
  if (correctAnswers[i] === userAnswers[i]) {
    correctCount++;
  }
}

console.log("Correct answers:" + correctCount);
console.log("Incorrect answers:" + (correctAnswers.length - correctCount));
```